# $F, G \in k[X_1, \dots , X_n]$ homogeneous of degrees $r$ and $r+1$ $\implies$ $F+G$ is irreducible

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have a question about Exercise 2-34 from William Fulton's *Algebraic Curves* book. The exercise is as follows.

> > Suppose that $F, G \in k[X_1, \dots , X_n]$ are forms (i.e. homogeneous polynomials) of degree $r$ and $r+1$ respectively, without common factors (where $k$ is a field). Prove that $F + G$ is irreducible.

I'm having some trouble trying to prove this. First, since $F, G$ are arbitrary I can't think of a particular irreducibility criterion to apply here, so my only idea was to try by contradiction.

---

**Notation**

I use Fulton's notation for the homogenization and dehomogenization of a polynomial with respect to the variable $X_{n+1}$. Say if $f \in k[X_1, \dots , X_n]$ has degree $d$, then its homogenization with respect to $X_{n+1}$ is denoted by $f^* = X_{n+1}^d f\left ( \frac{X_1}{X_{n+1}} , \dots , \frac{X_n}{X_{n+1}} \right)$.

Similarly, if $F \in k[X_1, \dots , X_{n+1}]$ is homogeneous, then its dehomogenization with respect to $X_{n+1}$ is denoted by $F_* = F(X_1, \dots , X_n, 1)$.

---

**My attempt**

Thus I assume by contradiction that $F + G$ is reducible, then there are polynomials $H,  R \in k[X_1, \dots , X_n]$ such that $F + G = HG$ and also $ 0 < \deg{H},\deg{G} < r + 1$. Then the homogenization is

$$(F + G)^* = X_{n+1} F + G = (HR)^* = H^* R^*$$

Now I'm somewhat stuck. I've tried to play around with this but without luck. I suppose that maybe I should try to get a contradiction to the assumption that $F$ and $G$ have no common factors, but I don't know how.

---

**My questions**

1. How can this be proved?
2. If my approach by contradiction is correct, how can the argument be finished?

As always, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you homogenize, the result is a *linear* polynomial in $X_{n+1}$ with coefficients in some field which just happens to be $k(X_1, ... X_n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Qiaochu. I was thinking about it. Let's see if I got it. Since a linear polynomial over a field is irreducible, then $(F+G)^* = X_{n+1} F + G$ is irreducible in $k(X_1 , \dots , X_n)[X_{n+1}]$ and since $F$ and $G$ have no common factors then the polynomial is primitive and therefore we can conclude that $(F+G)^*$ is irreducible in $k[X_1 , \dots , X_n][X_{n+1}]$. Am I right?

Comment: @Adrián: yep. Equivalently, by looking at degrees as polynomials in $X_{n+1}$ we see that either $H^{\ast}$ or $R^{\ast}$ has degree $0$ and hence must lie in $k[X_1, ... X_n]$.

Comment: Yes you're right, that was actually the first thing I wrote in my whiteboard when I was thinking about your answer, but then I thought about what I wrote above. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

Say that a non-zero polynomial $F$ has **width** $w\in\mathbb N_0$ if the degree of the monomial of highest degree appearing in $F$ with non-zero coefficient minus the degree of the monomial of lowest degree appearing in $F$ with non-zero coefficient is $w$. For example, if $F=F_{n+1}+F_n$ with $F_{n+1}$ and $F_n$ non-zero and homogeneous of degrees $n+1$ and $n$, the width of $F$ is $1$; notice that the polyonomials of width $0$ are exactly the non-zero homogeneous polynomials.

- Show that if $F$ and $G$ are polynomials with widths $w_F$ and $w_G$, then the product $FG$ has width $w_F+w_G$.
- Use that to prove that if a polynomial $F$ of width $1$, as in your case,  is reducible it necessarily has an non-constant homogeneous factor.
- Finally, use that to prove what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Mariano. I'll prove it this way also.